# Snowflake Equiv of PySpark STACK (LATERAL VIEW)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unpivot, lateral-join

I have working code using PySpark which uses the STACK function to turn columns into rows, creating a display_name column in doing so.

I am trying to convert this to a Snowflake query, in theory my thought was that a LATERAL JOIN should be able to do the job.

The below is very similar to what I have in PySpark, but for some reason I cant get it to work. I keep getting the below error:

`Invalid expression [T.ACTIVE_SHARE_PCT] in VALUES clause`

```
SELECT
    t.as_of_date,
    t.product_code,
    v.*
    
FROM (
    SELECT
        to_date(dd.date) AS as_of_date,
        pd.product_code AS product_code,
        pv.*
       
    FROM
        integration.product_valuation_accounting_fact_v01 pv
      
        JOIN integration.date_dim_v01 dd
            ON pv.valuation_date_key = dd.date_key

        JOIN integration.product_dim_v01 pd
            ON pv.product_key = pd.product_key
            AND dd.date BETWEEN pd.start_date AND pd.end_date

        LEFT JOIN integration.currency_dim_v01 cd
            ON pv.base_currency_key = cd.currency_key
        
    WHERE
        dd.date = '2023-06-30'
) AS t

CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    VALUES 
        ('Active Share End Weight', t.active_share_pct, null),
        ('Wtd Avg Market Cap Base', t.weighted_avg_mkt_cap_base, null),
        ('Price to Book Ratio – Latest Reported', t.price_book_ratio_latest_rptd, null)
) AS v (display_name, portfolio, benchmark)
```

I can't really use a UNPIVOT clause because I need to include any NULL values plus, i would be unpivoting two columns, the port and benchmark.

Comment: Some sample data and expected output would be of tremendous help.

Answer (score 0):

So if I makes so fake tables (as CTE's) the have the columns you use in your joins, and run this:

```
WITH product_valuation_accounting_fact_v01(valuation_date_key, product_key, base_currency_key) as (
    select * from values
        (100, 200, 300)
), date_dim_v01(date_key, date) as (
    select * from values
        (100, '2023-06-30')
), product_dim_v01(product_key, start_date, end_date, product_code) as (
    select * from values
        (200, '2023-01-01', '2099-01-01', 12345)
), currency_dim_v01(currency_key) as (
    select * from values
        (300 )
)
SELECT
    t.as_of_date,
    t.product_code,
    v.* 
FROM (
    SELECT
        to_date(dd.date) AS as_of_date,
        pd.product_code AS product_code,
        pv.*
    FROM
        /*integration.*/product_valuation_accounting_fact_v01 as pv
    JOIN /*integration.*/date_dim_v01 as dd
        ON pv.valuation_date_key = dd.date_key
    JOIN /*integration.*/product_dim_v01 as pd
        ON pv.product_key = pd.product_key
            AND dd.date BETWEEN pd.start_date AND pd.end_date
    LEFT JOIN /*integration.*/currency_dim_v01 as cd
        ON pv.base_currency_key = cd.currency_key
    WHERE dd.date = '2023-06-30'
) AS t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    VALUES 
        ('Active Share End Weight', t.active_share_pct, null),
        ('Wtd Avg Market Cap Base', t.weighted_avg_mkt_cap_base, null),
        ('Price to Book Ratio – Latest Reported', t.price_book_ratio_latest_rptd, null)
) AS v (display_name, portfolio, benchmark)
```

I get:

> Error: invalid identifier 'T.ACTIVE_SHARE_PCT' (line 37)

which is different to your error. Given `t` only has 2 known columns and "all of `PV` columns" I have to assume this are on PV, so we add those:

```
WITH product_valuation_accounting_fact_v01(valuation_date_key, product_key, base_currency_key, 
        ACTIVE_SHARE_PCT, WEIGHTED_AVG_MKT_CAP_BASE, price_book_ratio_latest_rptd) as (
    select * from values
        (100, 200, 300, 19.1::number(10, 2), 0.0123::number(20,10), 100::number)
), date_dim_v01(date_key, date) as (
    select * from values
        (100, '2023-06-30')
), product_dim_v01(product_key, start_date, end_date, product_code) as (
    select * from values
        (200, '2023-01-01', '2099-01-01', 12345)
), currency_dim_v01(currency_key) as (
    select * from values
        (300 )
)
SELECT
    t.as_of_date,
    t.product_code,
    v.* 
FROM (
    SELECT
        to_date(dd.date) AS as_of_date,
        pd.product_code AS product_code,
        pv.*
    FROM
        /*integration.*/product_valuation_accounting_fact_v01 as pv
    JOIN /*integration.*/date_dim_v01 as dd
        ON pv.valuation_date_key = dd.date_key
    JOIN /*integration.*/product_dim_v01 as pd
        ON pv.product_key = pd.product_key
            AND dd.date BETWEEN pd.start_date AND pd.end_date
    LEFT JOIN /*integration.*/currency_dim_v01 as cd
        ON pv.base_currency_key = cd.currency_key
    WHERE dd.date = '2023-06-30'
) AS t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    VALUES 
        ('Active Share End Weight', t.active_share_pct, null),
        ('Wtd Avg Market Cap Base', t.weighted_avg_mkt_cap_base, null),
        ('Price to Book Ratio – Latest Reported', t.price_book_ratio_latest_rptd, null)
) AS v (display_name, portfolio, benchmark)
```

> Invalid expression [T.ACTIVE_SHARE_PCT] in VALUES clause

yippie, it seems we have reproduced your problem...

right, now I read the code more, you are wanting to make 3 rows for each input row, and take one of three different values, but those values are coming from the input. Thus the `LATERAL`, but this is not really going to fly, instead, you should cross join to 3 values, and then use a CASE to access the values you wish like:

```
WITH product_valuation_accounting_fact_v01(valuation_date_key, product_key, base_currency_key, 
        ACTIVE_SHARE_PCT, WEIGHTED_AVG_MKT_CAP_BASE, price_book_ratio_latest_rptd) as (
    select * from values
        (100, 200, 300, 19.1::number(10, 2), 0.0123::number(20,10), 100::number)
), date_dim_v01(date_key, date) as (
    select * from values
        (100, '2023-06-30')
), product_dim_v01(product_key, start_date, end_date, product_code) as (
    select * from values
        (200, '2023-01-01', '2099-01-01', 12345)
), currency_dim_v01(currency_key) as (
    select * from values
        (300 )
)
SELECT
    t.as_of_date,
    t.product_code,
    v.display_name,
    case  v.type
        when 1 then t.active_share_pct
        when 2 then t.weighted_avg_mkt_cap_base
        when 3 then t.price_book_ratio_latest_rptd
    end as portfolio,
    null as benchmark   
FROM (
    SELECT
        to_date(dd.date) AS as_of_date,
        pd.product_code AS product_code,
        pv.*
    FROM
        /*integration.*/product_valuation_accounting_fact_v01 as pv
    JOIN /*integration.*/date_dim_v01 as dd
        ON pv.valuation_date_key = dd.date_key
    JOIN /*integration.*/product_dim_v01 as pd
        ON pv.product_key = pd.product_key
            AND dd.date BETWEEN pd.start_date AND pd.end_date
    LEFT JOIN /*integration.*/currency_dim_v01 as cd
        ON pv.base_currency_key = cd.currency_key
    WHERE dd.date = '2023-06-30'
) AS t
CROSS JOIN (
    VALUES 
        (1, 'Active Share End Weight'),
        (2, 'Wtd Avg Market Cap Base'),
        (3, 'Price to Book Ratio – Latest Reported')
) AS v(type, display_name)
```

giving:

[image]